# Order of class initialization during java deserialization

Tags: java, deserialization, static-initialization

During deserialization, are subclasses guaranteed to be initialized before any class instance objects are restored from the input stream? Specifically, I have a subclass with static fields that I'd like to access in the superclass `readObject()` method. Can I count on the subclass static fields being valid?

Comment: If you *mention* any class in your code it it guaranteed to be initialized *before your code runs.* Nothing to do with serialization specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert on BNF, but the [protocol spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html) for serialization

```
classDescInfo:
  classDescFlags fields classAnnotation superClassDesc
```

shows that superclass information comes **after** class information.  So it looks like you can rely on your subclass static fields.

Comment: Correct answer, misleading reasoning. Even if the protocol was defined differently, you are always guaranteed to have an initialized class, before an instance is created (unless you are creating the instance in the class initializer itself).